# Classifying relations as functions

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

so I'm having a bit of trouble actually working out the relation here, I'm fine with determining whether its a function/partialfunction etc I just don't understand how to produce the relation and get numbers etc.

This is the relation: $R = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} \mid y = x \}$

Can anyone teach me how I can work this out?

Thanks.

edit: would this be correct?

R = {(0,0), (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4) (5,5)...}

Comment: Your answer (by listing) is correct only if $\ x,y \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function $f:X\to Y$ is just a binary relation which is both functional and left-total (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Special_types_of_binary_relations)). The function in your question $f_R:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is just the identity function so it has a short description in the form $f_R(x)=x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

In general, a function $f:X\to Y$ need not have a neat description, you might have to specify the function in the form $\{(x,f(x)\mid x\in X\}$.

Comment: So by identify the function, do you mean assign a value to R, i.e. RxR so (0,0), (1,1) etc since the relation says y=x?

Comment: @Javanoob33, I'm not sure what {\em you} mean when you write "identify the function" (I did not use this term).

Comment: Sorry I misread your post, I thought you said identify but you actually said identity function. 

Thanks for your reply, but I'm still unsure how I can actually use that to determine whether it is a function etc?

Comment: @Javanoob33, So now you are asking how to determine if a given binary relation is functional and left-total?

Comment: I guess so, I just thought that the relation was meant to be converted into for example {(0,0), (1,1)} etc and then you determined whether it was a function/partial function etc from that?

Comment: @Javanoob33, you can write out the relation in the form of all pairs satisfying it, but it'll take an infinite amount of time since $\mathbb{R}$ is an infinite set. I suggest that you look at the definitions and examples given to you in class to better understand what you want to do. You can also take a look at the few examples given in the Wikipedia page I linked.